# Disable Screen Lock API in Chromium Browser

Tags: chromium

Is there a way to disable the Screen Wake Lock API in Chromium Browser, so that it cannot be used by websites / web app?

Background: I have an app (not mine, so I can't change the code) running in kiosk mode on a raspberry pi which unfortuneatly grabs a Screen Lock so the screen never switches off. I'd like to "override" that so that the screen goes to sleep normally.